# Applications that require a web server for full functionality

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, deployment

Is it possible to deploy an iOS application that requires a Node.js socket to do something on a computer?

For example:

Application -> Node.js socket -> Doing something on a computer

Computer does his job -> Response from Node.js socket -> Processing data with application

I don't think that Apple allows this, but one of my friends is sure about it. My point is that this solution does not reflect to an easy usage instead of making it a little bit complicated for average users.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. If you are asking if it is possible to release an iOS app that is dependent on a web service, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. I don't know how to integrate Node.js into app, but there are many other server that can be easily added to app, such as CocoaHTTPServer. I have created a project to manage files inside app sandbox. Open web page hosted by app to manage files. I know some other apps, which provide web page hosted by app to transfer media files.

Comment: Connecting to Node.js is no problem, we've already done that part.
The main problem was the fact that users must install node.js on their computer first, then using the app that requires it. So you're saying that it's possible to deploy them without any complication?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I know some apps that rely on app installed on Mac, such as Origami, Fuse, Splashtop, Duet Display. They communicate with mac app through network or usb. Is this the answer to your question?